surface area of a variety from its parametrisation
Suppose I have a two-dimensional semi-algebraic set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ given by a parametrisation $X = \{f(s,t) \mid 0 < s,t < 1\}$ for a nice function $f$. How would I find the surface area of $X$?

İ don't understand your parametrisation.  Can you give more information about it?

For example,  take $f$ to be a polynomial or a rational function.

Is $f$ a scalar function or a vector function?

Sorry, a vector function, I meant entrywise polynomial/rational
